# php - search a text file for content

Tags: php

i have a text file... the contents are as follows

```
---> t11  ---> x1  ---> 
---> t22  ---> x2  ---> 
---> t33  ---> x3  ---> 
---> t24  ---> x2  ---> 
---> t35  ---> x3  ---> 
---> t46  ---> x4  --->
```

how do i only search the first column and return the words that have t2 in the beginning... any help would be appreciated... i am using the following php code... but it only returns one word with t2 in the beginning, i want it to return all words with t2 in the beginning...

```
    <?php
$file = 'mytext.txt';
$searchfor = '---> t2';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    $strArray = explode('---> ',implode($matches[0]));


echo $strArray[1];

}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

the output should be something like...

```
---> t22
---> t24
```

Comment: use `fopen()`/`fgets()` in stead of using `file_get_contents()` to not load the entire file at once, if you have a rather big file

Comment: use `file()` in stead of using `file_get_contents()` if you have a rather small file. This will already return you an array with each line in it.

Comment: i think your `implode()` and `explode()` are swapped. At least you are exploding on `' ---> '`, but I have no idea where that string should be coming from. So I guess you want to `implode()` with it.

Comment: oh and the file has 120800 lines.....

Comment: sorry i had to edit the question... i was up till 4 am....

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fgets()` to go over the file line by line, search each line individually and display whatever you want in case you find it.

```
while (!feof($stream)) {
    echo fgets($stream); //Display each line
}
```

However, consider moving to a database with proper querying capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = 'mytext.txt';
$searchfor = 't2';

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$contents = file($file);
$matches = array();
foreach($contents as $lineNo => $line)
    if (substr(str_replace("---> ","",$line),0,strlen($searchfor)) === $searchfor)
        $matches[] = str_replace("---> ","",$line); // or use $matches[] = ++$lineNo . ': ' . $line;
if(count($matches))
    foreach($matches as $match)
        echo $match . "\n";
else
    echo "No matches found";
?>
```

Comment: @user2475714 I edited my answer as you have edited your OP question

Comment: i tried your code again and i get no matches found i want to search the first column and return all the words that have t2 in the beginning